# TDA api checking account balance

Tags: python, finance

I've been trying to use the TDA api to check my TD account balance but it can't figure it out and every time I try it gives me an error along the lines of "self not identified" here's my code

```
from td.client import TDClient
CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXX'
REDIRECT_URI = 'XXXXXXXX'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'XXXXXXX'
TD_ACCOUNT = 'XXXXXXXXX'

endpoint = r"https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/accounts"
   account_balance = TDClient.get_accounts(account = TD_ACCOUNT, fields = ['balance'])
   balance = pd.DataFrame(account_balance['balance'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try it this way:

```
from td.client import TDClient
from pprint import pprint

CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXXXXX'
REDIRECT_URI = 'XXXXXXXX'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = 'XXXXXXX'
TD_ACCOUNT = 'XXXXXXXXX'

td_client.login()
accountinfo = td_client.get_accounts(account = 'all')
pprint(accountinfo)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).